# How filter in a nested tree object without losing structure in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, tree

To display correctly a Tree view in React, I need to filter a nested tree object.

**I find this post :** 
[filter nested tree object without losing structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41312228/filter-nested-tree-object-without-losing-structure)

But actually I would like to do the exactly opposite. 
For instance, if in my filterData function `name === "a3`" I would like to keep object with `name === "a3"`

```
const result = filterData(items, "a3")
```

```
const items = [
  {
    name: "a1",
    id: 1,
    children: [
      {
        name: "a2",
        id: 2,
        children: [
          {
            name: "a3",
            id: 3
          },
          {
            name: "a5",
            id: 4
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "b2",
    id: 2,
    children: [
      {
        name: "a2",
        id: 2,
        children: [
          {
            name: "a3",
            id: 3
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "a4",
        id: 8
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

```
const result = [
  {
    name: "a1",
    id: 1,
    children: [
      {
        name: "a2",
        id: 2,
        children: [
          {
            name: "a3",
            id: 3
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "b2",
    id: 2,
    children: [
      {
        name: "a2",
        id: 2,
        children: [
          {
            name: "a3",
            id: 3
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create new objects without mutating the given data and reduce the arrays.

```js
function filter(array, name) {
    return array.reduce((r, { children = [], ...o }) => {
        if (o.name === name) {
            r.push(o);
            return r;
        }
        children = filter(children, name);
        if (children.length) {
            r.push(Object.assign(o, { children }));
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
}    

var items = [{ name: "a1", id: 1, children: [{ name: "a2", id: 2, children: [{ name: "a3", id: 3 }, { name: "a5", id: 4 }] }] }, { name: "b2", id: 2, children: [{ name: "a2", id: 2, children: [{ name: "a3", id: 3 }] }, { name: "a4", id: 8 }] }];

console.log(filter(items, "a2"));
console.log(filter(items, "a3"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nina, once again You save my day ! it works perfectly, now I have to read and read again to be sure to understand your proposal ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot, 
Actually, for instance for ```result = filter(items, "a2")``` it doesn't seem work, the under levels does not remove. 

I've tried to improve your code but I haven't find the solution yet... :( 

If we take the same items object than above, my result should be :

```javascript
const result = [
  {
    name: "a1",
    id: 1,
    children: [
      {
        name: "a2",
        id: 2,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "b2",
    id: 2,
    children: [
      {
        name: "a2",
        id: 2,
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: i see, no children for found node, please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

I've just improved the Nina's proposal in order to remove the under levels if "name" isn't include.

```js
function filter(array, name) {
  return array.reduce((r, o) => {
    var children;
    children = filter(o.children || [], name);

    if (children.length) {
      r.push(Object.assign({}, o, { children }));
    }

    if (o.name === name) {
      r.push(o);
      if (o.children && o.children.name !== name) {
        r[0].children = [];
      }
    }

    return r;
  }, []);
}

var items = [{ name: "a1", id: 1, children: [{ name: "a2", id: 2, children: [{ name: "a3", id: 3 }, { name: "a5", id: 4 }] }] }, { name: "b2", id: 2, children: [{ name: "a2", id: 2, children: [{ name: "a3", id: 3 }] }, { name: "a4", id: 8 }] }],

result = filter(items, "a2");

console.log(result);
```