# Antd Tree search is not expanding sublist children when searching with a value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, antd

Antd Tree search is not expanding sublist children when searching with a value, it is working fine with list and sublist but not with the sublist children.

Below is the sandbox link

https://codesandbox.io/s/controlled-tree-antd-4-19-1-forked-3h6fne

When I search I get like below, where there is search find under Data List Tree but it is not expanding

[image]

I am expecting it to come like below, It should also expand Data List tree as there is a search find under it. and eliminate remaining children which are not matching with the search key.

It is not opening sub-lists after searching

[image]

Finally, I need like below, after eliminating the un-matching values
[image]

Can Someone help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the changes for the answer, where Data List tree expanded as there is a search find under it. and eliminate remaining children which are not matching with the search key. Hope this helps someone :)

Referred below link and it  worked with all scenarios root level,sub root and final children search

I find this post :
filter nested tree object without losing structure
[How filter in a nested tree object without losing structure in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57218449/how-filter-in-a-nested-tree-object-without-losing-structure-in-javascript)

```
function searchFilter(array, name) {
  return array.reduce((r, { children = [], ...o }) => {
    if (hasSearchTerm(o.title, name)) {
      if (children) {
        r.push(Object.assign(o, { children }));
        return r;
      } else {
        r.push(o)
        return r;
      }
    }
    children = searchFilter(children, name);
    if (children.length) {
      r.push(Object.assign(o, { children }));
    }
    return r;
  }, []);
}
```

Attaching Codesanbox link :
https://codesandbox.io/s/controlled-tree-antd-4-19-1-forked-3h6fne?file=/index.js