# Search in multi dimension Array in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

I have this array with two object, and I have another array with these IDs: `[9054,9021,9040,8941,8947]`. I want to filter the big array and get a new array with only matched IDs on the second array.

The problem is to get the same configuration of the array, I want just to delete the unmatched IDs. Any idea how to solve it?

```js
const data = 
  [ { key: 9054, title: '22', children: 
      [ { key: 8959, title: 'ABR_ADRESSE', idFather: 8959, tableIsFamily: false, children: [] } 
      , { key: 8943, title: 'ABR_CONTACT', idFather: 8943, tableIsFamily: false, children: [] } 
      , { key: 9021, title: 'ABR_POSTE',   idFather: 9021, tableIsFamily: false, children: [] } 
      , { key: 8969, title: 'ABR_SOCIETE', idFather: 8969, tableIsFamily: false, children: [] } 
    ] } 
  , { key: 9040, title: '33', children: 
      [ { key: 8957, title: 'THB_Adresse_Famille', idFather: 8957, tableIsFamily: false, children: [] } 
      , { key: 8941, title: 'THB_Contact_Famille', idFather: 8941, tableIsFamily: false, children: 
          [ { key: 8947, title: 'THB_Contact_Table',     idFather: 8941 } 
          , { key: 9855, title: 'THB_Contact_Table_BIS', idFather: 8941 } 
        ] } 
      , { key: 8949,  title: 'THB_Societe_Famille', idFather: 8949,  tableIsFamily: false, children: [] } 
      , { key: 8983,  title: 'THB_TELEPHONE',       idFather: 8983,  tableIsFamily: false, children: [] } 
      , { key: 10070, title: 'THB_TEST_5708',       idFather: 10070, tableIsFamily: false, children: [] } 
  ] } ]
```

The expected Output should be :

```js
const data = 
  [ { key: 9054, title: '22', children: 
      [ 
      , { key: 9021, title: 'ABR_POSTE',   idFather: 9021, tableIsFamily: false, children: [] } 
      
    ] } 
  , { key: 9040, title: '33', children: 
      [ 
      , { key: 8941, title: 'THB_Contact_Famille', idFather: 8941, tableIsFamily: false, children: 
          [ { key: 8947, title: 'THB_Contact_Table',     idFather: 8941 } 
           
        ] } 
      
  ] } ]
```

Comment: Please add the expected output for the example you have given.

Comment: Please provide/show the expected outcome. It is unclear from your question what you expect to see as the result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter nested array in object array by array of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650390/filter-nested-array-in-object-array-by-array-of-values)

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: @pilchard, that question is not really about an arbitrarily deeply nested structure. Maybe there is a better dupe match.

Comment: It looks like a technical test question answer that you are looking for...

Answer (score 1):

Is this your expected output?

```json
[
  {"key": 9054,"title": "22","children": [
    {"key": 9021,"title": "ABR_POSTE","idFather": 9021,"tableIsFamily": false,"children": []}
  ]},
  {"key": 9040,"title": "33","children": [
    {"key": 8941,"title": "THB_Contact_Famille","idFather": 8941,"tableIsFamily": false,"children": [
      {"key": 8947,"title": "THB_Contact_Table","idFather": 8941}
    ]}
  ]}
]
```

---

You will need to loop over each child and recursively filter the children and check if the sub-child key exists within the keys array.

```js
const
  data = [
    {"key":9054,"title":"22","children":[
      {"key":8959,"title":"ABR_ADRESSE","idFather":8959,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]},
      {"key":8943,"title":"ABR_CONTACT","idFather":8943,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]},
      {"key":9021,"title":"ABR_POSTE","idFather":9021,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]},
      {"key":8969,"title":"ABR_SOCIETE","idFather":8969,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]}]},
      {"key":9040,"title":"33","children":[
        {"key":8957,"title":"THB_Adresse_Famille","idFather":8957,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]},   
        {"key":8941,"title":"THB_Contact_Famille","idFather":8941,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[
          {"key":8947,"title":"THB_Contact_Table","idFather":8941},
          {"key":9855,"title":"THB_Contact_Table_BIS","idFather":8941}
        ]},
        {"key":8949,"title":"THB_Societe_Famille","idFather":8949,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]},
        {"key":8983,"title":"THB_TELEPHONE","idFather":8983,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]},
        {"key":10070,"title":"THB_TEST_5708","idFather":10070,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]}
      ]}
    ];

// Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41312330/1762224
// For an in-place delete, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41312346/1762224
const filterTreeList = (data, opts) =>
  data.filter(item => {
    if (item[opts.childrenKey]) {
      item[opts.childrenKey] = filterTreeList(item[opts.childrenKey], opts);
    }
    return opts.keys.includes(item[opts.itemKey]);
  });

const result = filterTreeList(data, {
  itemKey: 'key',
  childrenKey: 'children',
  keys: [9054, 9021, 9040, 8941, 8947]
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```