# JS filter tree based on multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree

Let's say I have the following data structure:

```
const tree = {
  id: 'root',
  name: 'Root',
  children: [
    {
      type: 'foo',
      id: 'one',
      name: 'Name 1',
      children: [
        {
          type: 'account',
          id: 'account1',
          name: 'Account 1',
          children: [
            { id: '11', name: 'Asset 1' },
            { id: '22', name: 'Asset 2' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'bar',
      id: 'two',
      name: 'Name 2',
      children: [
        {
          type: 'sub',
          id: 'sub1',
          name: 'Sub 1',
          children: [
            { id: '11', name: 'Asset 1' },
            { id: '44', name: 'Asset 4' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

I need to add multiple filters support using AND based on the `type`, `accounId`, `assetName`, `subId`, etc.

For example, if I have the following filters:

```
{
  assetName: 'Asset 1'
}
```

I'm expecting to get only the relevant nodes.

If I have the following filters:

```
{
  assetName: 'Asset 1',
  type: 'bar'
}
```

I'm expecting to get only the second node.

How can I accomplish this? I only know how to do it with one single filter.

Comment: Please show the code you have and the code that works with a single filter.

Comment: @Bergi you can see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41312228/filter-nested-tree-object-without-losing-structure

Comment: @undefined Which one? Please [edit] your question to include your code.

Comment: Basically instead of `node.id !== condition` do `"id" in condition && node.id !== condition.id || "assetName" in condition && node.name !== condition.assetName` and so on

Comment: It is strange to filter by `assetName` when your tree objects do not have such a property. Why not first harmonise that? Also explain why you expect the second node to match that filter with 2 properties: that node doesn't have that name...?

Comment: @trincot assetName is the filter name which should match the last level ( see name: 'Asset x' )

Comment: Please explain how your "AND" is supposed to operate.  There are no nodes in the input which have both name of "Asset1" AND type of "bar".  So what precisely do you want the result to be.  Or should these be "OR"?  Do you want just the second node, with its one child with that child's first child only?  Something else?

Comment: *"should match the last level"*: There is nothing in your question that speaks about level related requirements. It speaks of "relevant" node, but what is relevant?